# Calculate expectation from empirical cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a empirical cumulative probability distribution function for a random variable. The random variable is "time to failure" and I have the full curve i.e till the probability reaches $1$. I want to know Mean Time To Failure i.e expectation of that random variable. Is there any standard method to find mean from an empirical distribution.

I am getting the empirical CDF (as discrete values) as output from a "model checking tool" which uses iterative numerical computation techniques to get those probabilities. For example, let $F(t)=P(X \leq t)$ is the CDF of the random variable $X$ where $X$ stands for time between failure. To plot the curve of "$F(t)$ vs $t$" I am varying t with some step size, calculating $F(t)$ for that t using the "model checking tool" and adding the points to get the curve. I can use small step size to get the more accurate curve. So, I have access to only this CDF values at different$ t$. From this values I want to do a good estimate of mean value of $X$.

Now the parameters will be:

1) $T$, the maximum value of t. We need to find this 
with some precision i.e if $F(T_1)-F(T_2)$ is less than some epsilon we set $T=T_1$.

2) Once we have found T we need to find suitable step size $h$ at which we will be
calculating the CDF values.

How should I choose those parametrs?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you've got your empirical cdf (discretized, formula) you might opt for Henning's answer, or also (given that the variable is positive) use this identity (obtained by applying [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Continuous_distribution_taking_non-negative_values)) :

$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty  (1- F(x)) \; dx$$

Comment: To improve this answer, you might consider supplying the explicit solution in the OP's case in terms of the atoms $\{x_i\}$ and the corresponding values of the empirical cdf $\hat{F}_n(x_i)$.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to a probability density by subtracting successive known values of the cdf and scaling appropriately. Then just compute $E(X)=\int x p(x) dx$ by multiplying and summing.

(Actually, telescoping the partial sums of this show that you can also just integrate the cdf:
$$E(X) = b - \int_a^b CDF(x) dx$$
with the integration interval ${[a,b]}$ chosen wide enough to include all the entire probability mass.)

Answer (score 2):

Relatively easily, if your empirical cdf has a maximum time T.  Let P(t) be your cumulative distribution function: the probability of failure before time t.  Then $p(t) = dP/dt$ is the probability density of failing at time t, and $E[t] = \int_0^T dt t p(t)$ is the Mean Time-To-Failure.  Integrating by parts, you find $E[t] = T - \int_0^T dt P(t)$, which you can do numerically.  If your empirical cdf has an arbitrarily long cutoff, it might be best to say, "our best estimate of Mean-Time-To-Failure is x, but 0.001% of our light bulbs still haven't burned out, so that mean could go up."

Comment: @all Thanks for reply. I have made some additions to the main question regarding the "choice of parameters" to get an accurate estimate of E[X]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but others may find the answer helpful.

Given the empirical CDF, $F_n(x)$, call the percent points of the CDF $\alpha$ (which range from $0$ to $1$) and their corresponding values $F_n^{-1}(\alpha)$ You can use the fact that:
$$
E(X) = \int_0^1 F_n^{-1}(\alpha);d\alpha
$$

This is actually the dual of the relationship @leonbloy stated, however, instead of adding up vertical slices across the x-axis from $F(x)$ to $1$, you are adding horizontal slices from the y-axis to $F(x)$ up to $y=1$. It is the same area.

To actually do the integration, I'd recommend the trapezoid rule, so given $n$ entries in the CDF we have:
$$
E(X) \approx \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{F_n^{-1}(\alpha_{k+1}) + F_n^{-1}(\alpha_{k})}{2}\cdot\left(\alpha_{k+1}-\alpha_{k}\right)
$$